# Django: query filter

Tags: python, django

I have two models that are related: one is a list of participants.  The other is a list of times they have checked in or out of an office.

The table (Checkin) has one record for every checkin/checkout pair.  So, there can be many records for any participant.

How can I retrieve only the very last (most recent) record for a participants checkin and then pass the participant and only that most recent Checkin record to my template?

From what I can tell there's no ability to do something like a last() in my template, so how would I go about filtering to get just that single record?

Thank you.

**Models:**

```
class Participant(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)


class CheckIn(models.Model):
    adult = models.ForeignKey(
        Participant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='adult_checkin')

    checkin = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**View snipit:**

```
    p_checkins = Participant.objects.all().order_by('created')

    queryset = p_checkins

    context_object_name = "the_list"

    template_name = 'list_of_checkins.html'
```

Comment: I'm not certain I understand how I can retrieve the full result set for displaying it within a template.  My goal would be to display something similar to the following in the django template:

Name       CheckIn               Checkout
John        7/19/22 10AM.      7/19/22 11AM
Jane.       7/19/22 7AM.        7/19/22 7:15AM

Comment: Here's a link to the full solution showing how to reference the related data within the template:  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73042139/django-queryset-to-include-and-filter-related-data)

Comment: Thank you for everyone's insight and willingness to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data through most recent **checkin** or **checkout**.

For checkin :

```
p_checkins = CheckIn.objects.all().order_by('-checkin')[0]
```

For checkout :

```
p_checkins = CheckIn.objects.all().order_by('-checkout')[0]
```

To get the participant name by :

```
name = p_checkins.adult.first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

**When you use (-) your latest update will be query from database.**

```
p_checkins = CheckIn.objects.all().order_by('-checkin')
```

or

```
p_checkins = CheckIn.objects.all().order_by('-checkout')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can annotate the latest value via a subquery to the participant

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
checkin_q = CheckIn.objects.filter(adult=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-checkin')
queryset = Participant.objects.annotate(last_checkin=Subquery(checkin_q.values('checkin')[:1]))
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers so far are correct in several aspects. One thing to note is that if your `check_in` or `check_out` values (whichever you use) isn't chronological (and by "most recent", you mean the last added), you'll want to add a `created_at` datetime field with [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) option `True`, or order by the `pk`.

In addition to the other answers provided and my comment above, you can also get the most recent check in by using the [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/relations/) on the participant object.