# Django Queryset to include and filter related data

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render a template with a list of participants (adult and minor) and their latest checkin and checkout times.

There are two types of participants and they are represented in two tables/models: AdultParticipant and MinorParticipant.  MinorParticipants have a foreign key relationship to the ParentParticipant.

Checkin information (checkin and checkout) is stored in a single table irregardless of whether the checkin data refers to AdultParticipant or the MinorParticipant. One record in this table captures the participant reference and the checkin and checkout times.

Any participant can have many checkins.  A checkin record can only have one participant.

The code as it exists now does everything I want except it displays every checkin record for the participant.  I only want to display the last (most recent) record for the participant.

How can I construct the queryset to include the participant information and include only the last checkin record for the participant?

Thank you in advance.  You are appreciated.

**Models**

```
class AdultParticipant(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)



class MinorParticipant(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        WaiverAdult, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='minor_of_adult')



class CheckIn(models.Model):

    adult = models.ForeignKey(
        AdultParticipant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='adult_checkin')

    minor = models.ForeignKey(
        MinorParticipant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='minor_checkin')

    checkin = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**View**

```
class WaiverListView(ListView):
    
    participants_and_checkins = AdultParticipant.objects.all().order_by('created')

    queryset = participants_and_checkins

    context_object_name = "the_list"

    template_name = 'list.html'
```

**Template**

```
{% for adult in the_list %}

  <tr>                         
   <td class="fs-6">

     {% for c in adult.adult_checkin.all|dictsortreversed:"checkin" %} 
               In: {{ c.checkin }}</br>
               Out: {{c.checkout}}</br>
     {% endfor %}
                         
   </td>
   <td>{{adult.last_name}}</td>
   <td>{{adult.first_name}}</td>
  </tr>


     {% for child in adult.minor_of_adult.all %} 
       <tr>
         <td class="fs-6">

           {% for c in child.minor_checkin.all|dictsortreversed:"checkin" %} 
               In: {{ c.checkin }}</br>
               Out: {{c.checkout}}
           {% endfor %}

         </td>
         <td>{{child.last_name}}</td>
         <td>{{child.first_name}}</td>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}


{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your template change `checkin.all` to `checkin.last`.

Also you can get rid of the for loop as well,like

```
In: {{ child.minor_checkin.last.checkin }}</br>
Out: {{child.minor_checkin.last.checkout}}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is this right:

pc = AdultParticipant.objects.all().order_by('created')

This is setting a variable that references each AdultParticipant object.

queryset = pc

This sets the queryset to the list of objects.

context_object_name = "the_list"

This sets the context allowing me to refer to all objects within the queryset.

{% for adult in the_list %}

Loops over each object in the queryset.

{{ child.minor_checkin.last.checkin }}

When this template tag is used, are we now making another call to the database and retrieving the associated objects?